# Combine multiple workbooks to one workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need to combine multiple workbook to one workbook.

Source workbooks have unique sheet name = "job"

Destination workbook have multiple sheets name

The Below code have 2 issues,

1. For loop not work
2. pasted data in Destination workbook create a new sheet. But i need to paste the data to existing sheet.

   ```
    Sub combine()
    'destination worksheets    
    Dim Ar As Worksheet
    Dim nr As Worksheet
    Set Ar = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetAr")
    Set nr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetnr")
    'Source workbooks
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FolderPath = Environ("userprofile" & "\Desktop\Copy")
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx*")
    Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim AW As Workbook

    Set AW = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Job")

     For Each AW In ws
     AW.Activate
     Cells.ShownAll
     ws.Copy Ar
     Next AW
     Workbooks(Filename).Close savechanges = True
     Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
   ```

Comment: Check on here - there are several different solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FolderPath = Environ("userprofile" & "\Desktop\Copy")` should be `FolderPath = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\Copy\"`.`For Each AW In ws` makes no sense since `AW` is a workbook and `ws` a worksheet. You probably meant `For Each ws in AW` but there is no need to loop if only `Job` sheet is the source. `Workbooks(Filename).Close savechanges = True` is missing `:` but since the workbook was opened read-only there are no change to save so use `.Close savechanges := False`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub combine()
 
    Dim wb As Workbook, rng As Range
    Dim wsAr As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String, Filename As String
    Dim iTargetRow As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    
    FolderPath = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\Copy\"
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx*")
 
    ' destination worksheet
    Set wsAr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetAr")
    iTargetRow = wsAr.UsedRange.Row + wsAr.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
        Set wsSrc = wb.Sheets("Job")
        Set rng = wsSrc.UsedRange
        
        rng.Copy wsAr.Cells(iTargetRow, rng.Column)
        iTargetRow = iTargetRow + rng.Rows.Count
        wb.Close savechanges:=False ' opened read only
        Filename = Dir()
        n = n + 1
     Loop
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     MsgBox n & " workbooks scanned", vbInformation
End Sub
```